unexpected output from suspected pointer arithmetic error
I am trying to build a linked-list in C++ from scratch. Consider the following commented class declaration.
/*
    Linked list goes from smallest to largest
*/
class List
{
public:
    List():head(0), tail(0), theCount(0) {}
    virtual ~List() {};
    void insert(int value);
    bool is_present(int value) const;
    bool is_empty() const { return head == 0; }
    void showAll();
    int count() const {return theCount;}
private:
    class ListCell
    {
    public:
        ListCell(int value, ListCell* cell = 0):val(value), next(cell) {}
        int val;
        ListCell* next;
    
    };
    ListCell* head;
    ListCell* tail;
    int theCount;
    
};

Once we create a List instance, we set the Head and Tail to the null pointers. To add values to the head, tail, and middle elements, I implemented the insert method.
insert:
void List::insert(int value) {
    theCount++;
    
    if (!head) {
        /*
            first insert sets the head and points to tail which is a nullPtr.
        */
        head = new ListCell(value, 0);
        //cout << "head is after initalization is " << head << endl;
        return;
    }
    if (!tail) {
            /*
                if tail is a nullptr, we set it to be the next node after head.
            */
            if (value > head->val) {
                /*
                    Value larger = therefore it should be the tail
                */

                tail = new ListCell(value, 0);
                head->next = tail;
                return;
            }
            else {
                /*
                    Value smaller, therefore, we swap.
                */
                tail = new ListCell(head->val, 0);
                head->next = tail;
                return;
            }
    }

            
    ListCell* previousNode = head;
    // the major problem, please advise me on the loop.
            for (ListCell* nodePtr = head; nodePtr->next; nodePtr++) {
                ListCell* next = nodePtr->next; // for convience
                if (next == tail) {
                    if (value > next->val) {
                        // if the value is the largest in the list.
                        int oldVal = tail->val;
                        tail->val = value;
                        next = new ListCell(oldVal, tail);
                        previousNode = nodePtr;
                        break;
                    }
                    else {
                        // if the value is just before the tail.
                        next = new ListCell(value, tail);
                        previousNode = nodePtr;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (value < nodePtr->val) {
                    /*
                        if value is less than the node's value, then we create a nodePtr
                    */
                    previousNode->next = new ListCell(value, nodePtr);
                    previousNode = nodePtr;
                    break;
                }
                previousNode = nodePtr;



                


            }
        


}

However, I am getting unexpected behavior when I try to showAll in my main function.
int main() {
    List mainList;
    mainList.insert(10);
    mainList.insert(12);
    mainList.insert(15);
    mainList.insert(11);
    mainList.showAll(); // shows undefined values. probably indirecting empty pointers
    return 0;
}


I have a feeling that it's the nodePtr++ that's causing problems because I am not used to pointer arithmetic.

Low-hanging fruit check didn't come up with anything obvious other than the leaks. I recommend adding in List::showAll in case it gives us a few more hints.

if (!head) and if (!tail) implies you can have a head without having a tail. That's not a particularly good plan. I'd think this through a bit more. The result of the thinking should make the code a LOT simpler.

You are right. pointer arithmetic is irrelevant here. It would be appropriate in an array, for a linked list you follow the links instead. An option might be to implement and use your own iterator including a definition of operator ++ for it that follows the links, but be sure to update links in the nodes/cells themselves when needed, if you do this.

Advice -- remove the comments and excessive blank lines in the code you posted.  Those comments and blank lines are contributing to the length of the post, where we need to scroll up and down to see the entire code block, plus it makes the code harder to follow with commented-out code, and comments where we all know what the code is doing (without those comments).

Here is an example of how simple the insert function could be if you abstract away the differences between head, next, and the previous node with an extra layer of indirection. All you need to add is tracking tail.

The node created with next = new ListCell(oldVal, tail); does not appear to be added anywhere. next is a local variable that only exists inside the loop. Assigning to it does not link the new node into the linked list because next is not a part of the list. previousNode-> next is part of the list.

End result after mainList.insert(15); the only items in the list are 10 and 15. 12 was lost. Fix the unknown bug in list::showAll , probably counting on the count member to be an accurate representation of the contents of the list rather than iterating to the first null next pointer, and call it after each insert so you can see the real contents of the list.

Before starting with raw pointers, you need to learn basics of resource management: RAII and rule 350 (and copy+swap idiom for beginners). Otherwise, you will end up with all sorts of runtime errors and undetected bugs. Your snippet is voilating rule 350 right now.

@user4581301 oh, should've just made it clear that showAll just cout all the node's values.

@user4581301 yeah, should have done more research on how linked-lists operate! but it was a good lesson nonetheless.

@AviBerger , I mean I was confused by your comment, but then I realized you just wanted to overload the operator since incrementing a pointer does not mean the next node.

@user4581301 while I did understand and used the answer's code, ext = new ListCell(oldVal, tail); is indeed wrong, but my thought process only used the nodePtr and nodePtr->next. I think replacing the value > next->val block to nodePtr->next(value, 0) and nodePtr.val = oldVal may actually have worked without using previousNode.

There are several issues, including the following:

In the !tail case, in the else block, a second node is created with the same value as was already present in the head node, and the given value is not used. So you'll not have inserted value, but have duplicated the first node.

In the main loop, nodePtr++ is wrong. You need nodePtr = nodePtr->next.

At several of the cases, you assign the new node to next. But this doesn't update the next member of the previous node. For that you really need to assign to previousNode->next and not just to next. You did this right in one case -- the last one -- but wrong in two other cases.

In the else block of the value > next->val case, there are still two possibilities: either value > nodePtr->val is true or it is not. But you don't check this, and deal with both cases in the same way. If it is not true, then the second argument of the ListNode constructor should be nodePtr, not tail. And if it is true, the assignment should be made to nodePtr->next and to previousNode->next otherwise.

Not a problem, but doing previousNode = nodePtr; just before the break is useless.

When the first node is added to the list, tail is left as nullptr, which the rest of your code seems to expect. But this is strange, since by the meaning of tail it should reference the last node of the list, even if there is only one node.

Even though fixing the above points will improve the behaviour of the code, you have over-complicated things. You've identified six places where to create a ListNode and insert it in some way into the list. This is too much. There really should be only two or three cases to deal separately with.


Here is what your code could look like when we reduce the number of different cases, and deal with the other points mentioned above:
void List::insert(int value) {
    theCount++;
    if (!head || value <= head->val) {
        head = new ListCell(value, head);
        if (!tail) tail = head;
        return;
    }
    ListCell* previousNode = head;
    while (previousNode->next && value > previousNode->next->val) {
        previousNode = previousNode->next;
    }
    previousNode->next = new ListCell(value, previousNode->next);
    if (tail->next) tail = tail->next;
}


Thank you so much! Sorry for the over-complication, it's my first time implementing a data structure from scratch!
